# Android Studios stopped loading import suggestions

Tags: android-studio

My Android Studios has recently stopped allowing me to automatically import unrecognized classes by hitting alt-enter on them (after I finished typing them out). I've uninstalled and reinstalled Android Studios, but the issue still persists.

Visual of issue:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/exHuQ.png
I type in Toast in one of classes. Once I have finished typing on click on the word "Toast", the ability for me to automatically import the class corresponding to "Toast" by hitting Alt-Enter is gone.

What is the cause of this issue and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

Ended up fixing it by doing: Go to 'File' > 'Invalidate caches/restart'